# rstrip On Lines of text being piped through sed s

Tags: regex, sed, pipe

So I am trying to implement the rstrip function on lines of text being piped into sed s and am having troubles. This is what I have that I think should work:

```
cat file1.txt | sed 's/[[:blank:]]+$//g;' > testrstrip.txt
```

When I test the code it does nothing to the input.

Here is an example of a test and a result (quotes in output are only there to show whitespace. All whitespace is spaces)

```
echo "babillion    "|  sed 's/[[:space:]]+$//g;' > testrstrip.txt
"babillion    "
```

The output also has a newline at the end that i could not show. any help on getting this working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why there are so many regular expression variants?](https://superuser.com/questions/449495/why-there-are-so-many-regular-expression-variants)

Comment: Thank you, adding -r fixed the problem.

Comment: `-E` is the portable equivalent.

Comment: even better! thanks